# How many degrees of freedom are used in this model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, econometrics, degrees-of-freedom

I have the table below, and I want to find the degrees of freedom for these data. Will my $k$ value from the formula $n-k-1$ include the dummy variables and `DIST^2`. That is, does $k=7$ or $3$, $4$, $5$, or $6$?

```
Dependent Variable: LFARE
Method: Least Squares
Date: 02/28/13 Time: 11:12
Sample: 1 4596
Included observations: 4596
Variable      Coefficient           Std. Error
C              4.770507             0.049427
LPASSEN        -0.080157            0.005603
BMKTSHR        0.301573             0.029724
DIST           0.000719             3.27E-05
DIST^2        -9.67E-08             1.21E-08
Y98            0.023120             0.013783
Y99            0.042357             0.013785
Y00            0.105950             0.013790

R-squared   0.428079
Adjusted R-squared 0.427206
```

Comment: Is `C` a constant / intercept? Are you trying to calculate the *residual* degrees of freedom? Note that we usually speak of the *model* having degrees of freedom, if you haven't done anything to your data (not even calculated a mean), then I suppose your data would have $n$ degrees of freedom, but I'm not sure how useful that is.

Comment: Degrees of freedom of what? You said "degrees of freedom for these data", but the *data* d.f. is $n$, not $n-k-1$. Do you mean the d.f. for the error term? Is this an ordinary regression model or something a bit more complicated?

Answer (score 4):

Yes $k$ includes all parameters less the intercept.  So all nonlinear terms and dummy variables need to be included.